# Google guva filter from list of arraylist

Tags: java, filter, collections, guava

Am trying to filter elements from list of arraylist using Google's Guava filter and its only supports for `Collection E`. I have to filter elements from `List of ArrayLists`.

Please find my below code that am working for it.

Is there any solution to filter elements from `List of Arraylists` ?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("Hello");
    list1.add("hi");
    list1.add("howdy");

    list2.add("are you good");
    list2.add("you doing");
    list2.add("was the day");

    list3.add("who");
    list3.add("how");
    list3.add("where");

    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list3);

    Collection<String> filtered=Collections2.filter(lists, Predicates.containsPattern("dy")); // not able to filter from List of ArrayLists.
    System.out.println("Filtered -->"+filtered);
```

**Update 1**

Please find my implementation below :

```
 Collection<Menu> menus = menuRepository.getMenus();

 Collection<ArrayList<Menu>> enabledMenus = FluentIterable.from(menus)
        .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
        .filter(byDisabled())
        .toList();
```

Am getting the below error

```
The method transformAndConcat(Function<? super Menu,? extends Iterable<? extends T>>) in the type FluentIterable<Menu> is not applicable for the arguments (Function<Object,Object>)
```

Please find my `byDisabled()` method implementation below.

```
  private Predicate<ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>> byDisabled() {
    return new Predicate<ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>>>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(ArrayList<ArrayList<Menu>> menu) {
        return isMenuEnabled(menu);
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Assuming you don't use Java 8, otherwise other answers already show possible solutions.)*

You need a [`.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) equivalent in Guava, which are:

- [`Iterables#concat(Iterable)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-)
- [`FluentIterable#transformAndConcat(Function)`](https://guava.dev/releases/28.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#transformAndConcat-com.google.common.base.Function-)

The latter can be used fluently (duh), similarly to Java 8 approach:

```
ImmutableList<String> filtered = FluentIterable.from(lists)
        .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
        .filter(Predicates.containsPattern("dy"))
        .toList();
```

Note that this *copies* contents of a resulting iterable, so if lazy `Iterable` is enough, last step could be omitted:

```
Iterable<String> filtered = FluentIterable.from(lists)
        .transformAndConcat(Functions.identity())
        .filter(Predicates.containsPattern("dy"));
```

Read more about [`Iterables`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#iterables) and [`FluentIterable`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#fluentiterable) on Gauva wiki.

Comment: I have followed it in my actual implementation. am facing some error during the implementation. I have updated that in my question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8's native stream API for this

```
List<String> filtered = lists.stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(Predicates.containsPattern("dy"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether `guava` is the only option for you, if not, Java 8 `stream` may work:

If you only want to find out the matched elements, try:

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

    list1.add("Hello");
    list1.add("hi");
    list1.add("howdy");

    list2.add("are you good");
    list2.add("you doing");
    list2.add("was the day");

    list3.add("who");
    list3.add("how");
    list3.add("where");

    lists.add(list2);
    lists.add(list1);
    lists.add(list3);

    List<String> matchedItems =
            lists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(str -> str.contains("dy")).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String item : matchedItems) {
        System.out.println("Matched item: " + item);
    }
```

Note, relation between element and sub-list is lost in this solution.